# How can i show iconButton by using ternary operator

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native

I would like to make the IconButton invisible when the imagePaths is an empty array through the ternary operator. But I want to show the iconButton only if the array contains values ​​like this: But when I use my code, I see the iconButton in any case.

how can i fix my code?

this is my code

```
    {imagePaths &&
    <IconButton iconName="cancel" onPress={onRemoveImage} />

    }


    console.log(imagePaths);

    // []  empty array

    // ["SampleFile_1619356823623.jpg"]  there is value in array
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just using `.length` to check array has data or not:

```
{imagePaths.length > 0 &&
  <IconButton iconName="cancel" onPress={onRemoveImage} />
}
```